# How to get back windows loader, or boot from ubuntu

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, usb, windows-7

Well, I have windows 7, I installed ubuntu using usb, but I missed up, so I deleted, But I loved ubuntu and I want it back.

The first time when I had to boot from usb I had a nice windows boot loader(or what ever) so I pressesd Esc and get to choose boot from USB, but now **The problem** is that I don't have that menu all I have is

```
Ubuntu
Advanced options for Ubuntu
Memory test
Windows 7 (loader)
```

So how to boot from USB?

Comment: Try pressing Esc before that menu shows up.

Comment: That didn't work

Answer (score 1):

That loader before was not the Windows bootloader; it was the BIOS boot device selection. As soon as the computer turns on, start pressing `Esc` repeatedly, until the boot menu comes up.

Comment: It didn't work or perhaps it's not Esc, what should I do in that case?

Comment: What brand of computer do you have?

Comment: I have a Toshiba

Comment: Ok. Toshiba has a few different keystrokes. What model?

Comment: I have C50 -A537

Comment: Try holding `esc`

Comment: Ok I 'll try again

Comment: No go, but thank's for the help any way

Comment: Try `F10` or `F12`. Remember, this is _right_ when the computer starts up and displays the BIOS screen.